# Why there are so few south americans working extensively at NA/EU unis?

Tags: career-path, university, south-america

May seem obvious, but don't strike me as such. I'm a undergrad physics student at University of Campinas, in Brazil. From what I took out of my professors, I noted that most, if not all, of them did their graduate education (mostly PhD or/and Post-Doc) in great universities in NA/EU, but, they obviously didn't stay. I'm, obviously, talking about a part of the professors here, since there are a lot of europeans, and some north americans who teach here.

I don't see much people from SA being able to secure extensive positions there, and I do wonder why it is so hard to do so. Obviously, it's already difficult for someone already from there, but it seems to be even harder for us here.

I'd like to understand, generally, what exactly could be the explanation for that, the fact that it's usual to see good south americans students being able to do a part of their education in those well-known unis, but being absurdly rare to see one stay. Seems like a vague question, but maybe there's something in the structure of the processes that could point out to it. Because, as far as undegraduates go, it's not really much different from NA/EU (when talking about the best universities here, which are not a lot).

Comment: Just as a quick fact: currently, I think faculty in STEM fields in the US have a hard time appraising the background of people from SA...

Comment: @paulgarrett Do you know why, exactly? I could vaguely understand why that would be the case for some unis here that could come out as "obscure", but for the high tier ones, I don't, particularly. Well, I'm talking about Brazil, specifically, I extended to SA because we do have south americans from other countries studying here, and some researchers as well, who follow pretty much the same "pattern" I described.

Comment: Anecdotally I find it easier to think of Argentinian physicists working in NA/EU than Brazilian ones. Instituto Balseiro is notable. Anyway, [this 2000 Physics Today article](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1325191) may be of some interest to you.

Comment: @Anyon heh, yes, it's true. I, myself, would immediately think of Maldacena, and another professor that, if I'm not mistaken, works at Oxford. There are some great ones. I'm really talking about Brazil specifically because it's pretty much my reference. But it's interesting, that aspect in Argentina.

Comment: Have you considered they might not have been interested in staying?

Comment: Unless you are from Patagonia, go to Norway for one winter semester and you will understand why not many people from SA have a position there.

Comment: I wonder if the statistics for Spain and Portugal are the same. Language comfort is possibly an issue for some.

Comment: One other factor might be *growth* within academia. Academia is fairly stagnant in the US and Europe, in contrast with the post-WW2 decades when there was explosive growth. In those days, many PhD students were able to become professors; these days, very very few do. I don't know much about the state of academia in South America generally or Brazil specifically, but is it possible that academia in Brazil is growing a lot? If so, it's likely much easier to get an academic job there for *anyone*, and certainly natives have an advantage (language, existing ties).

Comment: My professors in Oklahoma usually went to Stanford and Harvard, not Oklahoma universities. Professor jobs are hard, and elite universities graduate a lot more would-be professors than they can hire.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, the weather ?  Being near to family ?  The culture ?  We all tend to stay in the places we grow up in because they tend, for most people, to be where they feel most comfortable.

Answer (score 15):

South America has about 5% of the world's population.  It's certainly true that elite universities do not draw their people at random from the world's population, but no matter how they select people, there will not be many from South America.

Culture, language, and arbitrary bias (including visas) are big factors in academic immigration.

Comment: I do understand that. But, when talking about the specific subset of student who did manage to study at the "elite universities", that is, among those who, to some extent. already managed to overcome the completely accurate problems you've cited, it's really rare to see some manage to stay. That's the core of my line of asking, I would guess.

Comment: @Adrien-MarieDeschamps It's really rare for *anyone* to stay, even among those who study at elite universities. I have no idea quantitatively whether it's less likely for people from Brazil than other international students to stay in those countries or similar ones in academic positions, but I do wonder whether your perceptions are biased a bit by expecting too many to stay.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure the question even holds statistical water. I *believe* that in essence you say that the fraction of South American students in the US who end up being professors in the US is *smaller* than the fraction of European students who end up being professors in the US. Whether that is true or not can almost certainly not be determined without having actual statistical data. Since the fractions are small for both cohorts, and since everyone's sample is biased towards people like yourself, I doubt that the observation in the post is reliable.

But in addition, there are also many other factors. These may include:

- Do you have family in your home country you want to be close to? (The "pull" of the home country.)
- Does the culture you're from expect you to live close to your family? (Not so true for northern Europeans, for example, but very much true for Italians and in many Latin American cultures.)
- What is the standard of living you can expect if you go back to your home country? (If I went back to my home country Germany, for example, I would have to give up rather little compared to my home in the US now, and so there is not very much "push" from my home country to stay here. But if I had been from, say, Albania or now Ukraine, I might have good reasons not to go back to my home country.)
- What is the political situation in your home country? (If you're a political scientist originally from Russia, this may not be the time you feel a great pull to go back.)

In other words, there are a million reasons that *could* underlie the assertion -- but I am not convinced that the original assertion is even true.

Answer (score 3):

The way you formulate the question seems to imply that when one does a PhD or a PostDoc in NA/EU then will try to secure a position there simply because of the geographic factor (i.e. staying in NA/EU).

If your plan is to stay in a specific region of the world (it can be a region as big as *North America* or as small as *Copenaghen*), the ratio benefits/efforts is  strongly against academia and strongly in favor of the private world.

Additionally, you are only seeing the subset of people from SA that are now professor in SA. If anything, it tells you that in SA there are way less PhDs and PostDocs opportunities than what are needed. You should check what are the career of this SA professors from SA peers, so you should check their fellow PHDs that were in the EU/NA at the same time and check where they are now.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to make a link between the number of professors at your university with a graduate education in Europe or North America and the chance of these persons to get a faculty position there does not seem well-founded.

If you want to evaluate the chance of researchers from South America to get faculty positions in Europe or North America after doing a PhD or post-doc there, you will need to look at the respective ratio of PhD graduates to professors within Europe and North America and compare that according to region of origin.

Formulating your observation the other way round, it seems that few or maybe none of your professors got their graduate education locally. To find possible reasons for that observation, I would more look into the local education conditions or the recruiting strategies of your university than to how foreign universities recruit their professors.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to other answers it's difficult to give you the right answer without statistical data.

One number that striked me is the statistical fact that in Germany from 100 students (whose parents were already acedemians) 10 graduate with a PhD, and only 1 student with no academic parents.

In other words, academia is a highly socially selective branch, especially in Germany. You will not find many professors with a lower class ancestry. Of course you can further analyse and argue, students of lower social class have worse starting conditions than in middle or higher class. But, the IQ and education is actually in german quite equally and normally distributed and in a branch like academia people from lower class should actually have higher chances to move up to higher positions than in industry. Though, this seems not to be case empirically. Professors mostly come here from middle or high academic class also because the selection and hiring of new professors is in my opinion very conformstic and the right social reputation expected. Scientific or academic excellence alone don't guarantee you a professorship, social soft skills and networking are extremely important, more than in any other job branches.

These kind of social mechanisms and selection can also be strong factor why applicants from poorer countries might not be the first choice among the rich NA/EU unis?!

(Of course I expect strong critics here, but actually as the IQ is largely normally distributed among the population and social classes, one has to really ask and look for a good argument and strong factor, why academia is actively or indirectly socially discriminating so much, much much more than in other job branches.)

Comment: You're conflating a lot with your "in other words". First, graduating with a PhD doesn't make you a professor. There are various numbers around, but 3% of PhDs becoming professors seems pretty normal. Secondly, you're completely ignoring self selection; academia is usually not as lucrative as working in industry, and can be harder to break into; hence children of non-academians might be less likely to see value in such a job.

Comment: @prosfilaes you are backing me up... The selection for professorship is even more socially selective than PhD, this is the point I make. To make money in industry you need to have money or a social network of wealthy people. Of course therefore people from lower class would and do rather aim for a fixed job in public service if they are academically qualified for. This is also known by polls in Germany. Sorry, your comment is just guessing/wishful thinking but beyond reality. Fixed job in academia is the most easy and safe job in comparison, the current crisis and future recession proving it.

Comment: You claim that education is equally distributed after you state that education at the PhD level is not equally distributed. In the US, it's well known that a PhD in the right fields can easily make six figures, far more than a professor; what happens in Germany is moot for this question. There's no cites for anything you say, so it's impossible to verify or even analyze.

Comment: I'd be very interested in those studies you mention!

Comment: @guys I'm not here to google studies for you, I point you to things and share my wisdom and experience. It's obvious to anybody who worked 10-20 years in academica that it socially very selective or even discriminating, this will vary from country to country, in GER the ratio is as I wrote...and this even so the IQ and general high school education among low middle high class is pretty much equally distributed and not 1:2:10 or worse